# Access a selected date value in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, dom, datepicker

I have a jquery date picker

```
$('#from').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
    $('#to').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
```

which i am trying to access the just selected date field for use in some other code.

This fetches the entire form field code `console.log($("#from").get(0));` but i am only interested in the value that i can use in converting the dates to epoch

```
console.log($("#from").get(0));
    var from = $("#from").val().split('-');
    var to = $("#to").val().split('-');
    var epoch_from = new Date(from[0], from[1] - 1, from[2]).getTime() / 1000;
    var epoch_to = new Date(to[0], from[1] - 1, to[2]).getTime() / 1000;

    /**
    Epoch Stringfy
    */
    var from_string = epoch_from.toString();
    var to_string = epoch_to.toString();
```

How can i access the selected `from` and `to` values?.

Comment: You've already done so: `var from = $("#from").val()`....

Comment: This `console.log($("#from").val());` shows (an empty string).Would it be possible to hook something to the jquery datepicker so as to get `$("#from").val()` everytime i pick a date?.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). See mfarouk's answer to address your actual issue here. Don't needlessly reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onSelect` of `datepicker` and then you can use `ui` object which contains `selectedDay`, `selectedMonth` and `selectedYear` as separate values. That would be better for what you are trying to achieve:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dayObj;
    $('.checked').datepicker({
        onSelect: function (evt, ui) {
            dayObj = ui;
            console.log(ui.selectedDay, ui.selectedMonth, ui.selectedYear)
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="checked" />
<div class="a"></div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/358/

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function

```
var dateValue = $("#from").datepicker("getDate");
```

this function should return a date object